# Ember 4.6 <select> not showing current value

Tags: ember.js

Am I missing something in the following:

```
<select
  id={{@field}}
  name={{@field}}
  {{on "change" this.sendSelect}}
>
  <option value="null">Select one ... </option>
  {{#each this.data as |item|}}

  {{log "in record.hbs, curVal=" @curVal}}
  {{log "in record.hbs, item.id=" item.id}}
  {{debugger}}
    <option
      value={{item.id}}
      selected={{fn this.areEqual @curVal item.id}}
    >{{item.name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

The selected option is not being identified when the  is first loaded. The {{log}} statements show that one of the records have @curVal and item.id having equal values.  Using the {{debugger}} and

```
typeof  get(item.id)
```

and the same for @curVal shows they are both strings.

I originally used ember-truth-helpers, with

```
{{eq  @curVal item.id}}
```

but that never selects anything.  So I wrote a  local function:

```
@action
  areEqual(curval, itemId) {
    console.log('typeof curval', typeof curval);
    console.log('typeof itemId', typeof curval);
    return curval == itemId;
}
```

but it never seems to be called.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I resolved this by creating an Ember helper as suggested by @Krivaten during the discussion of this issue at: https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers/issues/39.  The 'eq' helper in the ember-truth-helpers add-on does a strict js comparison (===); the 'aeq' (almost equal)  helper suggested by Krivaten does a truthy comparison (==) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `fn`

```
selected={{this.areEqual @curVal item.id}}
```

`fn` *partially applies* arguments, and then returns a function that isn't invoked.

The syntax:

```
{{someFunction arg1 arg2}}
```

immediately invokes `someFunction`

Docs:

- https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/action-on-and-fn/#toc_the-fn-helper
- https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.6/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/fn?anchor=fn
- Syntax cheatsheet: https://cheatsheet.glimmer.nullvoxpopuli.com/docs/templates

Comment: Thanks for this; that worked.  But I solved the problem in a slightly different way (by defining a helper) as mentioned in the comment to my question.